# If I remove Visual Studio will this affect the Script files I previously did in the Unity project?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have decided to remove Visual studio; Because it does not auto-fill for me when I write the code, so I want to know if I delete it will that will affect the previous C# files I wrote in Unity !?

I haven't deleted it yet. I also went into the program settings to solve the autofill problem but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not.

Uninstalling Visual studio will not affect any project files as the uninstall program won't even know they exist.

I often have to uninstall and reinstall VS Code + VS 2022 when updates break it or I'm just quessing at issues and it has never removed my code files.

Answer (score 1):

No. As long as you don't delete the script files, you should be fine.